# Why is event.preventDefault(); not working here?

Tags: javascript, html

The browser URL is not supposed to be altered but it is anyway. That is supposed to be prevented by event.preventDefault() in the event listener for the cityNameSubmit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function bindButton() {
      document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      })
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose a City</legend>
        <input type="text" name="cityName" id="cityName">
        <input type="submit" id="cityNameSubmit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `bindButton` called ?

Answer (score 0):

You created a function but you forget to call this function. try this:

```
<script>
function bindButton() {
  document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  })
}
window.onload = function() {
bindButton();
}
</script>
```

Comment: And if he is trying to prevent the form from being send I would prefer to set `onsubmit="myFunction()"` to the form itself and then just use `myFunction() { event.preventDefault(); }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `bindButton()` somewhere or simply remove this function definition and leave just

```
document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: can't remove function definition because there's no "cityNameSubmit" id at the point of JavaScript execution.

Comment: If you can't remove it then just call this function after definition:
`<script>
function bindButton() {
....
}
bindButton();
</script>`

Comment: not right after definition, must be called after `<input type="submit" id="cityNameSubmit">` was created to avoid errors. There's still no element with that ID at the moment of `bindButton();` call. Solution could be separate `SCRIPT` block at the end of HTML or calling func in `onLoad` event.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in your actual code you are just declaring the function `bindButton()`, you have to call it in order to attach the event, for example in the `body onload` event, using `<body onload="bindButton()">` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function bindButton() {
      document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submission prevented !");
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="bindButton()">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose a City</legend>
      <input type="text" name="cityName" id="cityName">
      <input type="submit" id="cityNameSubmit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Or even better using an **Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)**, like this:

```
(function() {
  document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submission prevented !");
  })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose a City</legend>
      <input type="text" name="cityName" id="cityName">
      <input type="submit" id="cityNameSubmit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    (function() {
      document.getElementById('cityNameSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submission prevented !");
      })
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:**

Make sure to put the script at the end of the body tag, to ensure that the HTML was parsed.

Comment: I think an IIFE can also be used here, yes?

Comment: @cst1992 yes in fact, I was just editing my answer to include one.